# How do I mount my encrypted private home directory if I forgot the password?

Tags: ubuntu, encryption

On Ubuntu 12.04, how can I access encrypted private home directory? I forgot my root password at some point and my root home folder is locked. I am now using another account in root group so can I get access to encrypted home directory from this account?

Comment: Were you using your login password as the encryption password? (That's how Ubuntu does things by default.) If so, you'll have to remember the password.

Comment: it is all default thing i mean i haven't encrypted by my self!

Comment: If you have a user with `sudo` permissions, you can login to root with `sudo -i` and then run `passwd` to change the password...

Comment: If you could access an encrypted directory without specifying the password, there wouldn't be much point in encrypting the directory.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately for you, [ecryptfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecryptfs), the encryption system that Ubuntu uses for home directories, is not broken. So the only way to decrypt files is to know the password.

Comment: ... or, if the password was insecure enough, to brute-force it. It'll greatly help if OP remembers part of the password.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this will help you but you might have some luck trying the steps outlined in the recovery sections of the Ubuntu official documentation, titled: [EncryptedPrivateDirectory](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory#Recovering_Your_Data_Automatically).

Also there is this tutorial, titled: [How to Recover an Encrypted Home Directory on Ubuntu](http://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/).