# I have encrypted a folder on my Laptop and want to recover the previous version of it

Tags: linux, data-recovery

I have a folder with many files lets say /home/ibadski/Downloads/Mobiledata/
and mobiledata contains txt file and another folder structures.
I have now encrypted all the files in the folder and subfolder of Mobiledata.
and have forgotten the password. all of the files are now encrypted.
It is not possible to decrypt them due to computational reasons but can I get the PREVIOUS decrypted version of the files using data recovery? if yes what would you propose?

System Details:
Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
filesystem: ext-4

In order words lets say I have a file names foo.txt and then i encrypted it and it became foo.txt.locked.

Is there any way to get the previous version of the file?

Comment: You should add your system version and type of encryption. In the meantime the question [How do I mount my encrypted private home directory if I forgot the password?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108929/how-do-i-mount-my-encrypted-private-home-directory-if-i-forgot-the-password) has some answers.